# Mixing React and Knockout

Tags: reactjs, knockout.js

Our application has been written using Knockout. We would like to migrate the whole app to React, but it would require a lot of efforts at once.

Do you think if it is possible to create new features using React (like new queries, reports, options pages, etc.) while the existing code still remains in Knockout for a while, and in parallel migrate the existing Knockout code to React step by step? So soon or later the whole app would be written in React.

Or is it a bad idea and we should forget about mixing the two frameworks and start to rewrite the whole app from scratch instead?

Comment: This is very bad idea. React uses shadow DOM while knockout uses the viewmodel to control and refresh the page. In react, the changes to the DOM or the when `render` function runs is entirely dependent on updating the `state`. Mixing them will lead to all sort of problems

Comment: Both frameworks are meant to do exactly the same work -> update the DOM. But they're not designed to work together. This would definitely lead to loads of bugs and head-scratching